# How to activate "Share" button in android app?

Tags: java, android, xml, button, share

i want to add "Share" button to my android app.

Like that

[image: :]

I added "Share" button, but button is not active. I click, but nothing happens.

My code in MainActivity.java:

```
private ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.share_menu, menu);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.share_menu);
    mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) menu.findItem(R.id.share_menu).getActionProvider();
    mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(getDefaultShareIntent());

    return true;
}

{
    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Text");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share using"));
}
```

I want to share text in my first tab (first_tab.xml) or second tab (second_tab.xml).

Code in tab (xml) (If need):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/background_color"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity$DummySectionFragment" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/section_label1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@string/text"
    android:textColor="@color/text_color" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/sprite" />
```

Comment: To add this kind of Share button you need to use ActionBar / ActionBarSherlock and add ShareProvider.

Answer (score 317, accepted):

Add a `Button` and on click of the `Button` add this code:

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
String shareBody = "Here is the share content body";
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject Here");
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
```

Useful links:

[For basic sharing](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-implement-a-share-intent--mobile-8433/)

[For customization](https://clickclickclack.wordpress.com/2012/01/03/intercepting-androids-action_send-intents/)

Comment: Add the button where? I already created a menu item with the `share` icon in my Action Bar

Comment: Hello,
In above method it seems to display multiple applications.
I want to know which application used for sharing and after sharing complete i have to call one API.
Is to possible to check which application used and also how to call API after sharing?
Thank you...

Comment: It has been copied from https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-implement-a-share-intent--mobile-8433.

Comment: Works fine to me except to Facebook.
It does not show anything there, unfortunately.

Comment: how to add an image ? can u please suggest me ??

Answer (score 17):

Create a button with an id share and add the following code snippet.

```
share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {             
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
        String shareBody = "Your body here";
        String shareSub = "Your subject here";
        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, shareSub);
        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share using"));
    }
});
```

The above code snippet will open the share chooser on share button click action.
However, note...The share code snippet might not output very good results using emulator. For actual  results, run the code snippet on android device to get the real results.

Answer (score 6):

in kotlin :

```
val sharingIntent = Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND)
sharingIntent.type = "text/plain"
val shareBody = "Application Link : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=${App.context.getPackageName()}"
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "App link")
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody)
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share App Link Via :"))
```

Answer (score 1):

**Share Any File as below ( Kotlin ) :**
first create a folder named *`xml`* in the *`res`* folder and create a new XML Resource File named *`provider_paths.xml`* and put the below code inside it :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <files-path
        name="files"
        path="."/>

    <external-path
        name="external_files"
        path="."/>
</paths>
```

now go to the *`manifests`* folder and open the *`AndroidManifest.xml`* and then put the below code inside the `<application>` tag :

```
<provider
android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
android:exported="false"
android:grantUriPermissions="true">
<meta-data
    android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
    android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" /> // provider_paths.xml file path in this example
</provider>
```

now you put the below code in the `setOnLongClickListener` :

```
share_btn.setOnClickListener {
    try {
        val file = File("pathOfFile")
        if(file.exists()) {
            val uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file)
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
            intent.setType("*/*")
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri)
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        toast("Error")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Kotlin**

Inside the click listener needed to add this module for sharing text via applications like whatsApp, email, Slack..

```
shareOptionClicked.setOnClickListener{
     val shareData = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
     shareData.type = "text/plain"
     val dataToShare = "Text from my application"
     shareData.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject from my application")
     shareData.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, dataToShare)    
     startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareData, "Share Via"))
     }
```