# I can share the text of a layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, share

I can share the text of a layout in social networks or whatsapp, email?
Thank you.

I have this code:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(); 
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send."); 
sendIntent.setType("text/plain"); startActivity(sendIntent);
```

I could not program the button to share, thanks

Comment: Here is the solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17167701/how-to-add-share-button-to-android-app/17168698#17168698

Comment: Thanks, I can not set the button where I put this code?