# Share Button in My image application

Tags: android

How to make a share button in my image application so that when we press share button it share the current image to different option like whats app,facebook etc.Plz Answer That

Answer (score 2):

See the tutorial in the Android docs on [Adding an Easy Share Action](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/shareaction.html). It tells you exactly what you are asking.

That tutorial uses a `ShareActionProvider`, which is only since API 14. To support earlier versions of Android, take a look at the accepted answer in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17167701/how-to-add-share-button-to-android-app). [This third-party tutorial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-implement-a-share-intent/) also provides lots of good info.

Comment: `ShareActionProvider` is also supported via the AppCompat backport and the ActionBarSherlock backport of the action bar.

Comment: @CommonsWare - Good to know. I guess it kind of makes the other resources obsolete.

Comment: Well, the OP may not be using an action bar and wants a more traditional button, in which case `startActivity()` is the right answer.